# connect node js to postgresql (google cloud platform)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-connection

I have a node.js project running in gcp (cloud run) and a postgresql database,
when running the node.js project locally I manage to establish a connection
when running it on gcp it doesn't create my pool and I can't query things

here is my node code that creates the pool

```
  try {
    pool = new Pool({
      user: "postgres",
      host: "local_ip or public_ip i tried both",
      database: "postgres",
      password: "enter_password",
      port: "5432"
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Failed to start pool", err)
  }
```

to be able to get the connection to work on my local machine I had to add my ip to the connection part of the postgresql on gcp
I tried to add the result of

```
nslookup my-node.server-url
```

but it didn't work and then i tried to add an internal ip and use it but it also failed, how do you connect a node project with a postgresql db in gcp?!
would really appreciate the help

UPDATE: I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBrn5IM4mA8&ab_channel=GoogleCloudTech on yt that shows that you can connect with a socket but it doesn't show how to connect a cloud run instance to the cloud sql so that the socket is created...

Comment: From where are you connecting? GCP is not a product so please be more specific

Comment: my node service in cloud run

Comment: Have you already reviewed the docs? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run

Comment: Please let us know if the above comment helps you.

Comment: Well yeah I have seen these docs before posing the question, I feel like they are too complicated for me for some reason, I might have been quite burnt out when I read them but basically I just don't get which rules to add on what resources? looked at the service for example and there is no "cloudsql" role in the search there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the code sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connecting_to) for Node.js and sub in your proper variables (user, password, etc.) to allow your Cloud Run instance to connect to your Cloud SQL instance via Unix sockets. Then update your Cloud Run service by running:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE_NAME \
--add-cloudsql-instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Sub in your Cloud Run service name and Cloud SQL connection name into the command above to successfully connect the two services.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing this command